# Java - creating a loop for a filtering function

Tags: java, design-patterns, filter, java-stream, guava

I'm trying to figure out how to handle filtering project. I'm capable of filtering my collection by one field at a time (thanks to the guava Immutable.of) but I'm forced to create a way to filter my collection once again and again, until the user tells (for example, in switch) that he's done and wants to go back to the main menu.

```
private String filterOption() {
    System.out.println("What fields should I filter by? :\n" +
            "title\n" +
            "author\n" +
            "content\n" +
            "date\n");
    String filteringOption = scanner.nextLine();
    return filteringOption;
}

private String filterValue() {
    System.out.println("What value you want to use for filtering? :\n");
    String userInput = scanner.nextLine();
    return userInput;
}

public List<Message> filterMessages() {

    String filteringOption = filterOption();
    String userInput = filterValue();

    Map<String, BiPredicate<String, Message>> criteria = ImmutableMap.of(
            "title", (userTitle, message) -> userInput.equals(message.getTitle()),
            "author", (userAuthor, message) -> userInput.equals(message.getAuthor()),
            "content", (userContent, message) -> userInput.equals(message.getContent()),
            "date", (userDate, message) -> userInput.equals(message.getCreationDate())
    );

    BiPredicate<String, Message> predicate = criteria.get(filteringOption);

    filteredMessages = messageStorage.getAll().stream() //getAll() is to get entire collection
            .filter(m -> predicate.test(userInput, m))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    return filteredMessages;
}
```

Could someone show me a way to will allow user to use the values they've got from the filterMessages() to once again filter them using the same method? In short - filter what was once filtered until you are happy or there's nothing in the returned list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possibly something like :

```
List<Message> messageStorage = new ArrayList<>(); // messageStorage.getAll()
String userChoice = "";
while (!userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("No")) {
    messageStorage = filterMessages(messageStorage); // modifying the existing list
    System.out.println("Want to continue filtering? Yes/No");
    userChoice = scanner.next();
}
```

where I've just tweaked your `filterMessages` method as:

```
List<Message> filterMessages(List<Message> messageStorage) {
    String filteringOption = filterOption();
    String userInput = filterValue();
    Map<String, BiPredicate<String, Message>> criteria = ImmutableMap.of(
            "title", (userTitle, message) -> userInput.equals(message.getTitle()),
            "author", (userAuthor, message) -> userInput.equals(message.getAuthor()),
            "content", (userContent, message) -> userInput.equals(message.getContent()),
            "date", (userDate, message) -> userInput.equals(message.getCreationDate())
    );

    return messageStorage.stream()
            .filter(m -> criteria.get(filteringOption).test(userInput, m))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```